# Hover and click on hidden elements with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When i started using Selenium i found it difficult to perform actions (hover,click..etc) on hidden elements, which becomes visible only when hovered on some other element. so i hope this will help others, you can use any of the following ways..

For example, to `upvote` a comment in this page,i need to hover on the context (i.e. comment) to make upward arrow visible, then i need to click on it. But using `javascriptExcecuter` you can execute this in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//this can be used even if the element is not visible
//if you want to hover over the element, replace click() with hover() 
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('element_selector').click();");

OR

you can use Actions class rather than using the Keyboard or Mouse directly. 
It implements the builder pattern: Builds a CompositeAction containing all actions specified by method calls
```

[More info on Action class can be found here.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions)

Comment: `Keyboard`, `Mouse` and `TouchScreen` have all been deprecated and removed from WebDriver with the last patch: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: i could never imagine a user story that requires that the user hovers over a hidden element to make something happen.. it's preposterous - but interesting :P

Comment: actually in the scenario that i have mentioned , there are 2 elements, user will have to hover on one element to make the other element visible...which means the first element has to be visible for this to work..