# python selenium click nth element

Tags: python, linux, selenium

below is the inspected code, when the mouse is hovererd above the image, and basically i want the image to be clicked....

```
<ul id="product-list">

    <li class="product one-col new">
        <ul>
            <li class="image" title="sample image">
                <a href="#product/1d77e790-f74a-3859-97db-c513cbece39c">
                    <img width="" height="" alt="" src="/content/images/1.jpg"></img>
                    <span class="new"> … </span>
                    <span class="hover"></span>
                </a>
                <p class="retailer"> … </p>
                <p class="brand"></p>
            </li>
            <li class="price"> … </li>
            <li class="name" title="sample image"> … </li>
            <li class="first-seen"> … </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
```

i am using python selenium, and have tried the below to click the span (hover) link

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child > ul > li.image > a > span.hover ").click
```

however this does not work...any idea?

**update**:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child > ul > li.image > a > span.hover ").click()


 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.35.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace: 
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmp6Pgi9F/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8231)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmp6Pgi9F/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10823)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmp6Pgi9F/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10840)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp6Pgi9F/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10845)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmp6Pgi9F/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10787)
```

**update:**

this does not work too...

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child > ul > li.image > a ").click()
```

**update**:

also tried actionchains , mouse click..still no luck..

```
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child > ul > li.image")
    hov = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element)
    hov.click()
```

**SOLVED:**
finally this worked...

```
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child ")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
if "" == driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.hover").text:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.hover").click()
```

Comment: in ur solution, is that hover (variable name) the same one that is called later on "span.hover" ?

Comment: no..the first hover is a variable..the second one is a class name for span tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked:

```
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child ")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
if "" == driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.hover").text:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.hover").click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code missing `()`. Without `()`, `click` method is not called.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul...span.hover ").click()
#                                                             ^^
```

---

```
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child > ul > li.image > a > span.hover ")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'asdf';", element)
element.click()
```

Comment: thanks, now i get this... ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace:

Comment: @krisdigitx, The element does not contain any text. If I add some text to the element it works.

Comment: same here, it shows element does not exist, this is the main html source, http://pastebin.com/4h6aSvFp

Comment: @krisdigitx, new html source does not contain the element. ??

Comment: yeah i think its dynamic

Comment: @krisdigitx, Without accesing the reproducible html (or url), I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: what about just clicking the href instead of span(hover)

Comment: @krisdigitx, Try it. I can't try with the given html ;

Comment: had faced a similar issue with hover and click, was able to solve it using few ways, but i worked on java..here is a link which you can refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315560/perform-actions-such-as-hover-and-click-on-hidden-elements-selenium-webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315560/perform-actions-such-as-hover-and-click-on-hidden-elements-selenium-webdriver)...i dont know if this helps,but there is no harm in trying:)